# Rails, Mongoid and ordering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

My collections:

- Items
- Users
- Favorites

A user can favorite many items.

I want to serve items to each user ordered by the number of that user's friends that have favorited each item.

The problem I have is that items are not served all at once. A cursor has to be given between API and client in order to make infinite scroll work (so I can't order them all and then serve it).

At first I thought of creating an embedded document inside item with a field for each user representing the number of times that the user's friends favorited that item. But this will make the document grow (potentially) infinitely (not good).

Can anyone think of a good solution for this? Let me know if you need further details.

Comment: what you need is a graph database like Neo4j. since its been 4yrs like to know how you solved this.